# bookshelf.js where and has query at same time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to return from our db a query where:

event_id = event.attributes.id 
user_to  = user.id 
stripeCharge IS NOT NULL

I think I can do this use the [has](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-has) feature in bookshelf. I can't seem to get both the where & has going at the same time. Here is what my query that works with just where:

```
analyticsPayments.where({
    event_id: event.attributes.id,
    user_to: user.id
}).fetch().then(function(payment) {
    console.log(payment);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
res.status(500).json(err);});
```

I tried putting in after the where .has(stripeCharge) but it didn't like that.

Any idea how to achieve what I am trying to do, or how to have both a where and a has clause?

Thanks

Comment: I think `model.has` is a instance method.

Comment: Thanks @RajAdroit does that mean that it can only be called on the returned "payment" in my case?

Comment: Yes, if you want to achieve before query, You may use Model validation

Comment: So it can't be done in the same query? As in .where(x).has(x).fetch() @RajAdroit